# BroadcastReceiver in Android dagger 2.11

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, broadcastreceiver, dagger-2

I m trying to inject broadcast receiver with dagger in android. I m using dagger 2.11. I have BroadcastReceiver module class, component class, and I implement HasBroadcastReceiverInjector in Application class. Do I have to implement HasBroadcastReceiverInjector in Application class, or I can implement HasBroadcastReceiverInjector in Activity class. Has anybody successed to inject BroadcastReceiver with dagger, or someone knows what am I doing wrong

Here is my BroadcastReceiver module class

```
@Subcomponent(modules = LikeBroadcastReceiverModule.class)
public interface LikeBroadcastReceiverComponent extends AndroidInjector<LikeBroadcaseReceiver> {

@Subcomponent.Builder
abstract class Builder extends AndroidInjector.Builder<LikeBroadcaseReceiver>{}}
```

Here is my BroadcastReceiver module class

```
@Module
public class LikeBroadcastReceiverModule {

@Provides
public LikeBroadcastReceiverView provideBroadcastView(LikeBroadcaseReceiver likeBroadcaseReceiver){
    return likeBroadcaseReceiver;
}

@Provides
public BroadcastReceiverPresenter providePresenter(){
    return new BroadcastReceiverPresenterImpl();
}}
```

Here is my Application class

```
public class EasyDriveApplication extends Application implements HasActivityInjector, HasBroadcastReceiverInjector{

@Inject
DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity> activityDispatchingAndroidInjector;

@Inject
DispatchingAndroidInjector<BroadcastReceiver> broadcastReceiverDispatchingAndroidInjector;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    //Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
    DaggerAppComponent.builder().application(this).build().inject(this);
}

@Override
public AndroidInjector<Activity> activityInjector() {
    return activityDispatchingAndroidInjector;
}

@Override
public AndroidInjector<BroadcastReceiver> broadcastReceiverInjector() {
    return broadcastReceiverDispatchingAndroidInjector;
}}
```

and here is my AppComponent class

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {
    AndroidInjectionModule.class,
    AppModule.class,
    DaoModule.class,
    MapperModule.class,
    UseCaseModule.class,
    ThreadingModule.class,
    UtilsModule.class,
    BroadcastReceiverBuilder.class,
    ActivityBuilder.class
    })
public interface AppComponent {

@Component.Builder
interface Builder {
    @BindsInstance
    Builder application(Application application);
    AppComponent build();
}

void inject(EasyDriveApplication app);}
```

and my BroadcastReceiverBuilder class is looks like

```
@Module
public abstract class BroadcastReceiverBuilder {

@Binds
@IntoMap
@BroadcastReceiverKey(LikeBroadcaseReceiver.class)
abstract AndroidInjector.Factory<? extends BroadcastReceiver> bindLikeBroadcastReceiver(LikeBroadcastReceiverComponent.Builder builder);}
```

This is error I get

> Error:(46, 10) error: com.presentation.dagger.broadcastReceiver.LikeBroadcastReceiverComponent.Builder cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
>   com.presentation.dagger.broadcastReceiver.LikeBroadcastReceiverComponent.Builder is injected at
>   com.presentation.dagger.application.module.BroadcastReceiverBuilder.bindLikeBroadcastReceiver(builder)
>   java.util.Map,javax.inject.Provider>> is injected at
>   dagger.android.DispatchingAndroidInjector.(injectorFactories)
>   dagger.android.DispatchingAndroidInjector is injected at
>   com.presentation.dagger.application.EasyDriveApplication.broadcastReceiverDispatchingAndroidInjector
>   com.presentation.dagger.application.EasyDriveApplication is injected at
>   com.presentation.dagger.application.AppComponent.inject(app)

Comment: I believe you forgot adding `LikeBroadcastReceiverComponent` as a subcomponent to your `@Module(...) BroadcastReceiverBuilder`. Do it like you would with an activity or fragment

Comment: I do it just like activity, but it doesn't work. I read somewhere that I should inject same as activity, but it is not work. I think that I added `LikeBroadcastReceiverComponent` as subcomponent. You can check first code that I shared @david

Comment: You will have to add it as a `@Module(subcomponents=yourcomponent.class)` as I mentioned

Comment: You were right. Thank you very much. I don't have idea how I could forgot that stuff. Thank you one more time

Answer (score 0):

I found this page whilst trying to find a way of dependency injecting into a BroadcastReceiver, for anyone else who hits on an issue here is how to do it

```
@Provides
fun providesBlah() : Blah = Blah()

class BlahBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

@Inject
lateinit var blah: Blah

override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
    (context.applicationContext as MyApplication).component().inject(this)
}
```

}